# how include span in link_to erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to write this HTML in ERB:

```
<a href="/" id="logo">One<span id="red>Two</span></a>
```

How do I include the span?

```
<%= link_to "ONETWO", root_path, id: "logo" %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline:

```
<%= link_to(raw('One<span id="red">Two</span>'), root_path, id: "logo")  %>
```

Answer (score 5):

just use the [block form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) of this helper :

```
<%= link_to root_path, id: :logo do %>
  One<span id="red>Two</span>
<% end %>
```

Other helpers support this form, like `content_for`.